# Efficient way to read big text file, parse each line, and query to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I have a big UTF8 text file (~ 10 millions lines; contains CJK characters). Each line contains tab-delimited fields like:

```
field1    field2    a_id    b_id    c_id    ...   fieldN
```

My Java program needs to

1. read each line
2. parse each field
3. use a_id, b_id, c_id to query to
   several different MySQL tables
4. compose a new line with all fields
5. output each new line to a file

Pseudo code like below:

```
String line   = nextline
Entity entity = parse(line)

// check cache and query to table A
if (cacheA not contains entity.a_id)
    // select values from tableA where id = entity.a_id

// check cache and query to table B
if (cacheB not contains entity.b_id)
    // select values from tableB where id = entity.b_id

// check cache and query to table C
if (cacheC not contains entity.c_id)
    // select values from tableC where id = entity.c_id

// compose and output
append_to_file(
    compose(entity, resultA, resultB, resultC)
)
```

Even I can use thread or something for MySQL queries:

```
new thread { // check cache and query to table A }
new thread { // check cache and query to table B }
new thread { // check cache and query to table C }
join all threads

// compose and output
```

I'm still worrying about that there may be too many IO to MySQL and cost too much time.

I'm wondering if there's any better way to do the MySQL selection queries ?
or any better way than read/write files line by line ?

(I MUST use Java 1.6 and MySQL 5.1.)

(I can use 3rd-party libraries like guava and Apache Commons.)

I appreciate if you can provide any advice. Thanks.

Comment: *"I'm still worrying about that there may be too many IO to MySQL and cost too much time"* - Have you tried anything yet to see what impact that it has?  Don't try to prematurely optimise your solution under you know that there is actually a problem. For example. You could use a fixed thread executor to place each "desired" query into a pool and then allow the executor to simply pluck the next query from it when it has a thread available.  This way, you can control the number of active queries hitting the database, but you're not sacrificing performance on one side of the fence or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are tables A,B,C?  If they are not too big, read them entirely (3 `SELECTs`) and build hash tables mapping a_id => a_value.  Then use those hashes instead of using MySQL 10 million times.

If that was not viable, the break the input into, say, 100-line chunks.  Get the 100 a_id values, do a single SELECT with a long `IN` to build the hash table.  Ditto for B and C.  Then process the 100 lines.

(I suggest 100 because it is probably manageable, and because going to, say, 1000 probably won't speed things up more than a few percent.)

Comment: Thanks. I am going the chunks approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're on a hurry to solve your issue but consider using a framework like [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) to solve your problem. The learning curve isn't steep for newbies/experienced spring users and you will have flexibility and power from the framework.